# Why doesn't $.add() work as expected? Trying to build up jQuery collection manually

Tags: jquery

I don't understand why the following code doesn't work. (jQuery 1.6.4)

HTML:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test me"></div>
<div class="test me"></div>
<div class="test me"></div>
```

JS:

```
var rows = $([]);

console.debug('Divs we want: ', $('div:not(.me)').length);

console.debug('Rows before: ', rows.length);

$('div:not(.me)').each(function() {
    if (1==1) { // some conditional
        console.debug($(this));
        rows.add($(this));
    }
});

console.debug('Rows after: ', rows.length);
```

Comment: what do you mean by not work???

Comment: `$([]);` should just be `$()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) builds and returns a new jQuery object from the contents of the one it's called on and the argument you supply. It does not update the object it's called on.

You probably want to write:

```
rows = rows.add(this);
```

As an aside, since jQuery 1.4 the canonical way to construct an empty jQuery object is to call `$()` without arguments:

```
var rows = $();
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, I didn't realize jQuery was creating a new collection with that call :)

Answer (score 5):

The reason why is that `add` returns a new jQuery object with the added element.  It doesn't modify the existing jQuery object inline.  You need to capture this result.  Change

```
rows.add($(this));
```

To

```
rows = rows.add($(this));
```

Note: As Rocket pointed out it's much simpler to remove the extra object and simply say

```
rows = rows.add(this);
```

Comment: Note: you can do `rows = rows.add(this);`, saves a call to the jQuery function.